# Why is my last digit being omitted while reversing?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reverse print a number. So far my code is ..
The reason I put `> 10` was that because if I have a number  89 % 10 => I get 9 but for something less than 10 like 7 % 10 =>  I get 0

```
int reverse_num(unsigned long int offset) {
    int revnum = 0;
    while(offset > 10){
        int remainder = offset % 10;
        revnum = (revnum * 10) + remainder;
        offset = (offset - remainder) /10.0;
    }
    return revnum ;
}
```

But the problem is if I pass in the actual parameter as 8963 , it is returning 369. i.e, it's omitting 8 . But why ?

Comment: What would your code do if `offset` was 3?

Comment: `7 % 10` is 7, not 0. It looks like your workaround for this non-problem is causing the actual problem. Also, you don't need `(offset - remainder) / 10.0`; just use `offset / 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was happening because your loop condition was wrong,  you should be terminating when `offset` is equal to 0 and not when its smaller than 10, that way you skip one digit

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int reverse_num(unsigned long int offset) {
    int revnum = 0;
    while (offset){
        int remainder = offset % 10;
        revnum = (revnum * 10) + remainder;
        offset = (offset - remainder) /10.0;
    }
    return revnum ;
}

int main() {
    cout << reverse_num(8963) << endl;
}
```

---

Also keep in mind that there is a danger for overflows here when the `unsigned long int` is too large to fit in an `int`

Comment: `while (offset)` is same as `while (offset != 0)` ?

Comment: yep, `while (offset)` means while `offset` is non-zero, which is logically the same thing as `while (offset != 0)`

Comment: Okay thanks ! upvoted . But I'mma have to wait for 10 mins for accepting according to SO :p